# ng-content angular2 does not work for botstrapped component

Tags: angular

I've created ContentPage component as follows:

```
@Component({ selector: 'content-page',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>' })
export class ContentPage {
}
```

and then bootstrapped it within the module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [ ContentPage ],
    bootstrap:    [ ContentPage ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The page template is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  ... angular2 quickstart head ...
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px">
      <content-page>
        <div style="float: right; width: 150px">
          <content-button-edit></content-button-edit>
        </div>
        <div data-page-id="{{page-id}}">
          Some content here
        </div>
      </content-page>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the page loads, the "Some content here" appears for a moment and then disappears. I suppose that it should be inserted instead of ng-content in the ContentPage's template as I have ng-content directive in it. When I change the page template, it changes the output so it is definitely applied.

Is there a way to preserve the markupped content of the component?

Update:

What I want to achieve is to generate the HTML page with content on server and then just add the dynamic functionality.

As the content-button-edit should actually hide "Some content here" and display edit page control instead, I'm thinking about using the container component that contains both  and .

So template or templateUrl are not the options.

Comment: See also https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3146-you-cannot-project-static-content-into-the-root-component-in-angular-2-0-0.htm

Comment: why not just add the markup within the `content-page` selector in the html where that is defined?

Comment: The content of the content-page should be created on the server. So the template/templateUrl is not the option, I think.

Comment: @yurzui Hm... that's sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'content-page',
  template: document.querySelector('content-page').innerHTML
})
export class AppComponent { 
  pageId = 1;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px">
  <content-page>
    <div style="float: right; width: 150px">
      <content-button-edit></content-button-edit>
    </div>
    <div [attr.data-page-id]="pageId">
      Some content here
    </div>
  </content-page>
</div>
```

See **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/sCDSJeO73Os2aglejpb6?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Create an html page for your component as a html file. `content-page.component.html`. This can be in the same folder of the component you are writing. then in your `@Component`

```
@Component({ 
     moduleId: module.id,
     selector: 'content-page',
     templateUrl: 'content-page.component.html' 
})
  export class ContentPage {}
```

Then in your `content-page.html`

```
<div style="float: right; width: 150px">
   <content-button-edit></content-button-edit>
 </div>
 <div data-page-id="{{page-id}}">
    Some content here
 </div>
```

Your "selector" (`content-page`) would need to be defined / called from your module as a declaration

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit not in line what I'm trying to achieve. The page content is a wiki page, rendered on the server. So the content is different and depends on the URL.

Comment: well what you are doing now is outside the bounds of the component based approach, you cannot embed content in a selector. You embed the logic for that selector in the component. . The reason it "appears for a moment" is because that is the "moment that the component loads. That is where your page loader should be. Sounds like you need to create a pipe

Comment: From another hand what I'm doing is inline with search engine optimisation and the angular's own site http://angular.io - they generate page on the server and then just add the dynamics on top of it. With components, indeed.

Comment: can you provide a link because this does not seem inline at all

Answer (score -2):

you missed to add moduleId

```
@Component(
 { 
    **moduleId: module.id,**
    selector: 'content-page',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>' })
export class ContentPage {
}
```